# Import Sequences From Swiss-Prot Fasta File

Tags: python, fasta

I´m working with the fasta file from swiss-port (ftp://ftp.uniprot.org/pub/databases/uniprot/current_release/knowledgebase/complete/uniprot_sprot.fasta.gz) where in the lines that start with '`>`' we have some information of the protein in in the next ones the amino acid sequence.

Is there a way to search through the lines using the gene name (in the line depicted as "`GN=xxxxxxx`" being the `x`'s the name of the gene) and import the sequence that comes in the lines afterwards?

I'm struggling with this since I'm having troubles searching in the middle of the line and creating the loop to copy the next lines.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Linux, familiarize yourself with `sed`, `awk` and `tail/head`. They will save you a lot of time in the future.

Let's assume we are looking for gene FV3-002L

```
sed -n '/GN=FV3-002L/,/^>/p' uniprot_sprot.fasta | head -n -1
```

`-n`: tells sed only to print when told so

`GN=FV3-002L`: your search term

`^>`: the end of your search, `^` is the beginning of a line, `>` the beginning of the FASTA header

`/p`: tells sed to print the match

`| head -n -1`: let's get rid of the last line (too lazy to find a better regular expression, but you get the idea)

---

Using Python:

```
gene = 'FV3-002L'
gene_found = False
fasta = ''
with open('uniprot_sprot.fasta') as f:
    for line in f:
        if gene in line:
            gene_found = True
            fasta += line
        elif gene_found and line.startswith('>'):
            break
        elif gene_found:
            fasta += line

print(fasta)
```

The script opens your uniprot file, reads each line, checks if the gene name is found, and if yes, it reads every line until the next header and finally prints the FASTA sequence.

Please note: Those snippets work for a single example but can be adapted for multiple genes as well. If you want to do this routinely, it is worth looking for more efficient ways of dealing with data. For manipulation of biological data, you could also look at [BioPython](http://biopython.org/).